# rollup-plugin-replace not doing expected replacement

Tags: reactjs, rollup, rollupjs

I have a React module which is bundled using Rollup.

I need this absolute import

```js
import(`/public/assets/flags/${name}.svg`)`
```

to become a relative import like this in the bundle:

```js
import(`./public/assets/flags/${name}.svg`)
```

I'm trying to use rollup-plugin-replace but it is adding an extra "dot" that I can't identify where is coming from

`rollup.config.mjs` plugins array looks like that.

```js
plugins: [
      styles(),
      commandLineArgs.debug && debug(),
      json(),
      resolve({ browser: true }),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({
        tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
        clean: true,
        transformers: () => ({
          before: [
            transform({
              overrideIdFn: '[sha512:contenthash:base64:6]',
              ast: true,
            }),
          ],
        }),
      }),
      downlevelRegex(),
      svgr(),
      importMetaAssets(),
      copy({
        targets: [
          {
            src: 'public/assets/**/*',
            dest: 'dist/public/assets/',
          },
        ],
      }),
      replace({
        preventAssignment: true,
        values: {
          '/public/assets/flags/': './public/assets/flags/',
        },
        exclude: 'node_modules/**/*',
        delimiters: ['', ''],
      }),
    ],
```

The output in the `bundle.esm.js` is like this, with an extra initial dot.

```js
 import(`../public/assets/flags/${name}.svg`)
```